Einstein Bot: Why Is the Question Step Not Triggered After Rule Step?
I am working on an Einstein Bot in Salesforce and have encountered an issue where a question step does not automatically trigger after a rule step. Here is the setup I currently have:
I have a Rule Step that evaluates a condition and determines the routing type using an Omni-Channel flow.
Immediately after the Rule Step, I added a Question Step to ask the user for their first name.
Despite placing the Question Step immediately after the Rule Step, the bot does not proceed to the question step as expected.
Steps I Followed:
Created a Rule Step with specific conditions and actions (e.g., setting routing type).
Placed a Question Step right below the Rule Step.
Configured the Question Step to ask, "May I know your first name?" and saved the response to a variable.
Problem:
The Question Step is not being triggered automatically after the Rule Step is executed.
What I Need Help With:
Is this the correct way to configure the bot for such a scenario?
Are there additional settings or best practices I should follow to ensure the question step works after a rule step?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
